# Regular expression to replace string except in sqaure brackets

Tags: c#, regex

Need to replace all forward-slash (`/`) with `>` except for the ones in the square brackets

input string:

```
string str = "//div[1]/li/a[@href='https://www.facebook.com/']";
```

Tried pattern (did not work):

```
string regex = @"\/(?=$|[^]]+\||\[[^]]+\]\/)";
var pattern = Regex.Replace(str, regex, ">");
```

Expected Result:

```
">>div[1]>li>a[@href='https://www.facebook.com/']"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking was good with lookbehind but instead positive use negative.

```
(?<!\[[^\]]*)(\/)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0kajGc/1)

After updating your c# code

```cs
string pattern = @"(?<!\[[^\]]*)(\/)";
string input = "//div[1]/li/a[@href='https://www.facebook.com/']";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, ">");
```

You will get

```
>>div[1]>li>a[@href='https://www.facebook.com/']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to also use `String.Replace` you can do the following:

```
string input = "//div[1]/li/a[@href='https://www.facebook.com/']";
        string expected = ">>div[1]>li>a[@href='https://www.facebook.com/']";

        var groups = Regex.Match(input, @"^(.*)(\[.*\])$")
             .Groups
             .Cast<Group>()
             .Select(g => g.Value)
             .Skip(1);
        var left = groups.First().Replace('/', '>');
        var right = groups.Last();
        var actual = left + right;

        Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
```

What this does is split the `string` into two `groups`, where for the first group the `/` is replaced by `>` as you describe. The second `group` is appended as is. Basically, you don't care what is between square brackets.

(The `Assert` is from an `xUnit` unit test.)

Comment: not worked for input ="//div[1]/a[1]/span[@class='_55pe'][1]"

Comment: If you expect `">>div[1]>a[1]>span[@class='_55pe'][1]"`, this passes my tests.

Answer (score 0):

You could either match from an opening till a closing square bracket or capture the `/` in a capturing group.

In the replacement replace the `/` with a `<`

Pattern

```
\[[^]]+\]|(/)
```

- `\[[^]]+\]` Match from opening `[` till closing `]`
- `|` Or
- `(/)` Capture `/` in group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q8A3I3/1) | [C# demo](https://rextester.com/RXXXB85307)

For example

```
string str = "//div[1]/li/a[@href='https://www.facebook.com/']";
string regex = @"\[[^]]+\]|(/)";
str = Regex.Replace(str, regex, m => m.Groups[1].Success ? ">" : m.Value);
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Output

```
>>div[1]>li>a[@href='https://www.facebook.com/']
```

Comment: This removes everything inside brackets e.g. "//div[@class='_6a _3bcy'][1]" is converted to "div>:nth-child(1)"

Comment: @SandeepDhamale I can not reproduce that. See that it works with the current code https://rextester.com/YIVF99799